# Nonhomogeneous second-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to calculate $$x''+5x'+4x=t^2e^{7t}$$
Roots of this equation's characteristic polynomial are $\lambda_1=-1$ and $\lambda_2=-4$. What should I do now?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/768785/55235) might interest you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions of the homogeneous equation are
$$x_h(t)=\alpha e^{-t}+\beta e^{-4t}$$
now we look for a particular solution on the form
$$x_p(t)=(at^2+bt+c)e^{7t}$$
so substitute this function in the given differential equation to find $a,b$ and $c$ and finally the solutions are:
$$x=x_h+x_p$$

Comment: Nice!${}{}{}{}$