# How to solve $y^{\left(4\right)}-6y^{\left(3\right)}+9y''=x+\cos3x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could you please give me some hint how to solve this equation?
$$y^{\left(4\right)}-6y^{\left(3\right)}+9y''=x+\cos3x$$

I find that the solutions of homogeneous equation are $y_1=1,y_2=x,y_3=e^{3x},y_4=xe^{3x}$,
but could not calculate the particular solution of non-homogeneous.
I tried to apply method of variation of parameters and this way did not bring me to solution,
probable because some miscalculation.

Are there a less tedious way to solve this equation ?

Thanks.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768755/how-to-solve-y-y-2-sinx/768785#768785) answer.

Comment: Thank you, but I could not comprehend how this post may help in my case. Would you be so kind to explain more ?

Comment: Find a particular solution of the form $ax^2+bx^3+c\cos3x+d\sin3x$.

Comment: Let $\varphi$ be a particular solution of $y^{\left(4\right)}(x)-6y^{\left(3\right)}(x)+9y(x)''=x$ and $\psi$ be a particular solution of $y^{\left(4\right)}(x)-6y^{\left(3\right)}(x)+9y''(x)=\cos3x$. Each of this can be solved by the method in my answer. Now note that $\varphi+\psi$ is a particular solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A particular solution can be found by simply guessing: it should be a polynomial of at most degree $3$, coupled with a trigonometric factor of argument $3x$.

Thus,
$$y_0(x)=A \cos (3 x)+B \sin (3 x)+ax+b x^2+c x^3$$
Comparing to the non homogeneous term you should get:
$$b=1/27,\ c = 1/54,\ A = 0,\ B = 1 / 162$$

Comment: Of course, the $ax$ term is superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

Let $D$ be the differentiation operator, so your equation is $$D^2(D-3)^2y=x+\cos3x$$ Note that $D^2x=0$, and $(D^2+9)\cos3x=0$, so $D^2(D^2+9)(x+\cos3x)=0$. So $$D^4(D-3)^2(D^2+9)y=0$$ which is a homogeneous equation, and it appears that you know how to solve homogeneous equations.

Comment: And I hope the OP knows that only four of the eight constants are arbitrary, and the other four have to be evaluated to get rid of the extraneous solutions introduced by differentiating.