# Solving Differential equation $y"+2y'-3y= x-4e^{-3x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

solve the equation $$y"+2y'-3y= x-4e^{-3x}$$

In this i have solved for particular solution but since $3$ is a root of homogeneous equation $y"+2y'-3y=0$ i am not able to find the value of coefficient of $e^{-3x}$. PLease help me.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768755/how-to-solve-y-y-2-sinx/768785#768785) answer.

Comment: Amzoti that gives 9x-4c=4

Comment: Yeah that worked. :) thnk u :)

Answer (score 0):

First you solve the homogeneous equation using $y_h = \mathrm{e}^{r x}$

\begin{align*}
& y_h^{\prime \prime} + 2 y_h^{\prime} - 3 y_h = \\
& r^2 + 2 r - 3 = 0 \\
& \implies r = -1 \pm \sqrt{4} = -1 \pm 2
\end{align*}

So $y_h = C_1 \mathrm{e}^{-3 x} + C_2 \mathrm{e}^{x}$.

As a next step you try to find particular solutions. Note that the differential equation is linear, you can therefore find a particular solution for both terms on the right hand side separately and simply add them up in the end.

As the first one $(x)$ is a polynomial of order 1, try finding a particular solution of the form $y_{p1} = a x + b$.

The second one is trickier, as $\mathrm{e}^{-3 x}$ is already a homogeneous solution, you cannot use $A \mathrm{e}^{-3 x}$ as an approach. Instead you should look for a solution of the form $y_{p2} = A(x) \mathrm{e}^{-3 x}$. Take $A(x) = B x$ and you should be able to solve it.