# Second Order Differential Equations - Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

When solving for this one:

$y''-3y'-4y=e^{-x}$

For the trial function, let:

$y=Ae^{-x}$

$y'=-Ae^{-x}$

$y''=Ae^{-x}$

$=> Ae^{-x}-3(-Ae^{-x})-4(Ae^{-x})=e^{-x}$

$=> Ae^{-x}+3Ae^{-x}-4Ae^{-x}=e^{-x}$

$=> 0=1$

I keep getting this answer, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Try $y(x)=Axe^{-x}$. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768755/how-to-solve-y-y-2-sinx/768785#768785) answer.