# On a substitution to solve a high order differential equation (exercise).

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have solved Linear first order differential equations, I know how to separate variables, for higher orders I know the the substitutions that apply to the bernoulli equation and homogeneous equations.

The exercise asks to solve:

$$y^{(4)}+ 4y^{(2)}+4y = cos2t - sin2t$$

I am given a hint that : $$r^4+4r^2 + 4r^0 = 0 \implies (r^2+2)^2 = 0 \implies r = \pm i \sqrt{2}$$

Could I have a reference to how to solve these kind of differential equations? Or am I just missing a trick that makes this a first order?
I tried thinking about substituting Eulers formula in the left hand side but I am missing an $i$.

Comment: I believe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768755/how-to-solve-y-y-2-sinx/768785#768785) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

hint: use the fact that $e^{i\sqrt{2}t}=\cos(\sqrt{2}t)+i\sin(\sqrt{2}t)$