# Using method of undetermined coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here's the equation I'm working with: 
$y''+y'-2y = 3e^x+4x$

I want to use the method of undetermined coefficients for this equation. The logical choice for our guess would be $y = Ae^x+Bx+C$.

After substituting in, we end up getting $Ae^x + Ae^x+B - 2(Ae^x+Bx+C) = 3e^x+4x$.

While we get a value for B, -2, it doesn't quite work out for A and C. Thoughts?

Comment: y = c1e^(-2x)+c2e^(x)

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768755/how-to-solve-y-y-2-sinx/768785#768785) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that, if $y=Ae^x$, then $y''+y'-2y=Ae^x+Ae^x-2Ae^x=0$. Therefore, the $Ae^x$ term in your so-called "logical guess" is not contributing anything. That's why you should **solve the homogeneous equation first**, before you try to find a particular solution. The general solution of the homogeneous equation is $y=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-2x}$, and you can see from that $c_1e^x$ term that $Ae^x$ is useless in guessing a particular solution. **Hint:** Try replacing $Ae^x$ with $Axe^x$.

Answer (score 0):

When you said A doesn't work it, it's because A disappears from the equation, correct?  A disappears because $e^x$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation.  I assume you know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: ... That is true, it is a homogeneous solution. If a solution appears twice .... multiply by x? And then add xe^(x) as a solution?