# third order linear ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this equation:

$$y'''-y' = 4Ce^x +3Ce^{-x} $$

I know that the general formula is $Y = Y_h + Y_p$

I also know that this equation can be reduced to 2nd order by integrating it so it will now be:

$$y" - y = 4C_1e^x - 3C_2e^{-x} + C_3$$

I can get the $Y_h$ by:

$m^2 - 1 = 0$

roots are now then $m_1 = 1, m_2 = -1$.

$$Y_h = C_1 e^x + C_2 e^{-x}\\
r(x) = 4C_1e^x - 3C_2e^{-x} + C_3$$

now my problem here is that I am not quite sure how do i get the $Y_p$ of this equation and if it is possible to solve this without reducing it to 2nd order but maintaining the 3rd order.

My guess for $Y_p$ is:

$$Y_p = (C_1 e^x + C_2 e^{-x} + C_3)x$$

I multiplied $x$ base on the modification rule that $Y_p$ variables should not be present on your $Y_h$

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768755/how-to-solve-y-y-2-sinx/768785#768785) answer.

Comment: thanks i get the Yh part but i still need some confirmation for my Yp part.

Comment: @Amzoti care to explain why? I did the x part based on the modification rule where no part of the Yp should be equal to yh.

Comment: My answer gives you $y_p$.