# Solving $y'''-y''-y'+y = 3e^t + 5t\sin t$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What method could I used to solve this differential equation $y'''-y''-y'+y = 3e^t + 5t\sin t$?

I seems like it should be something along the lines of the undetermined coefficients, but I'm not sure if I can use the method in this case. Could anyone guide me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768755/how-to-solve-y-y-2-sinx/768785#768785). Apply this method to $y'''(t)-y''(t)-y'(t)+y(t)=3e^t$ and to $y'''(t)-y''(t)-y'(t)+y(t)=5t\sin(t)$ separately and think about how that helps.

Comment: Could you fix the last term, please ? Is is $5 t \sin(t)$ ? As well as the $y'$.

Comment: I'll try this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the homogenous equation solve the characteristic equation $$\lambda^3-\lambda^2-\lambda+1=0$$ and for a particluar solution make the ansatz
$$e^x(A+Bx+Cx^2)+\sin(x)(Ex+F)+\cos(x)(Gx+H)$$

Comment: @GitGud. Why does $C=0$ a priori ? Just curious.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I've wrongly answered your comment, hope you didn't read it. I deleted my previous comment too, I had made a silly mistake. But, as per my linked answer, what I said is indeed true. To be honest I don't recall the proof anymore, I'm sure it's in any intro to ODE book.

Comment: @GitGud. I didn't have time to read it ! I really wonder what silly mistake **you** made ! Cheers :-)