# Solve $2y''-3y'+y=(t+1)e^t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm not sure how to solve this problem using the method where you guess what the solution should appear like. I'm assuming the solution is of the form $e^t(At^2+Bt+C)$ but I have no idea how to do this.  If anyone has any other ways to solve this problem that would be really helpful.  My professor hasn't been helpful about how to solve problems like this so I'm confused.  Thanks!

Comment: Set $(\alpha, \beta)=(1,0)$ [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768755/how-to-solve-y-y-2-sinx/768785#768785).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that guess will work to find a particular solution. We can even guess $v(t)=e^t(At^2+Bt)$ to get:
$$2v''(t)-3v'(t)+v(t)=(4A+B+2At)e^t$$
So $A=\frac{1}{2}$ and $B=-1$, hence a particular solution is:
$$v(t)=(\frac{1}{2}t^2-t)e^t=t(\frac{1}{2}t-1)e^t$$
Now the general solution to the inhomogeneous case:
$$2u''(t)-3u'(t)+u(t)=0$$
is ($C_1$ and $C_2$ arbitrary constants):
$$u(t)=C_1 e^{t/2}+C_2 e^t$$
So the final solution will be:
$$y(t)=C_1 e^{t/2}+C_2 e^t+t(\frac{1}{2}t-1)e^t$$
I am using a well known theorem in the study of inhomogenous linear differential equations that the general solution is the sum of the homogeneous case and a particular solution. If you're not familiar with this, and your professor doesn't seem to help you, you can read more, including a proof here: http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-NonhomgenLinEqns_Stu.pdf

I suggest you get familiar with this method of solving inhomogenous linear differential equations, since it is in my opinion the easiest one. The most difficult part will be to get a feel for which form to guess for the particular solution, for which practice really is key.

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to do this. we will make a change of variable. let 
$$ y = ue^t, y' = u'e^t + u e^t, y'' = u''e^t + 2u'e^t + ue^t$$ substituting these in $$(t+1)e^t = 2y''-3y'+y =e^t\left(2(u''+2u'+u)-3(u'+u)+u) \right) =e^t\left(2u''+u'+u) \right)$$ that is $u$ satsfies the simpler 
$$2u''+u'=t+1 \tag 1$$ look for a particular solution of the form 
$$u = At^2 + Bt, u'=2At + B, u'' = 2A $$ is a solution of $(1)$ if $$4A + 2At + B = t + 1, \ A = 1/2 \ and \ B = -1  $$  so a particular solution is $$y = \left(\frac 12 t^2 - t\right)e^t. $$