# How do I solve this linear differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$y''-9y'=e^x$ is the original equation.

I substitute y for $e^{cx}$ so I get

$C^2e^{cx}-9ce^{cx}=e^x$

What do I do with the $e^x$?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768755/how-to-solve-y-y-2-sinx/768785#768785).

Comment: First, what is the general solution, that is, have you considered $y''-9y'=0$?

Comment: I didn't understand any of that. Can you help with the e^x?

Comment: C=0,9 imranfat.

Comment: It's hard to understand if you don't use Latex. The General solution is not C=0,9

Comment: It would be y(x)=A1+A2e^9x correct?

Comment: If the first suggestion is too difficult for you, then take a look at http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RealRoots.aspx

Comment: Or this one https://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121027202833AA8nn8b

Comment: set $c = 1.$ that gives you a particular solution.

Answer (score 0):

you have alread found a particular solution by trying $y = Ae^x.$ putting this in the differential gives you $$ Ae^x - 9A e^x = e^x \to A = -1/8.$$ now you can find the solutions of the associaed homogenous equation $$ y'' - 9y' = 0 $$ by trying solution of the form $$y = e^{kx} \to k^2 - 9k = 0 \to k = 0, 9 $$ therefore by the principle of superposition you have the general solution $$y = A + Be^{9x} - \frac 18 e^x .$$

Comment: How did you get -1/8 , im confused

Comment: @user222222, look at the first equation. we have $-8Ae^x = e^x.$  cancel the $e^x$ and you are left with $8A = -1$

Comment: I'm referring to the y'' turning into Ae^X, why is that? and same with y'

Comment: @user222222, if $y = Ae^x, $ then $y' = Ae^x, y'' = Ae^x$

Comment: How come Y= Ae^x

Comment: @user222222,  because the right hand side of the equation has $e^x,$  we can try looking for a solution of the form $y = Ae^x.$

Comment: Last question, in what form must be the answer? why is it just A and then B and then y(p)

Comment: they are solutions of the differential equation with the right hand side set to zero. if you have initial conditions on $y$ and $y'$ then that will fix the $A$ and $B.$. feel free to ask and i will respond as best as i can.

Comment: Can you tell me the format of the solution?

Comment: @user222222, i don't understand what you mean by the format of the solution.

Comment: For example for linear equation it'd be ax^2+bx+c, what would it be for this question

Comment: @user222222, what is the linear equation? what is $ax^2 + bx + c?$ how are these related to the differential equation you have here?

Comment: I'm asking you what format is A+Be^x9+(e^x/8)

I didn't mean Linear, I meant quadratic, my mistake

Comment: this is the sum of the homogeneous solution and a particular solution. a particular solution in this case being $-\frac 18 e^x$ that we found by trial.