# Help solving differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I  would like to know how to classify  the following equations:

$y''+ 4y'+5y=2e^{-2x}cos(x)$.

Is it a second order linear equation?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768755/how-to-solve-y-y-2-sinx/768785#768785).

Comment: @GitGud I did something similar, but I have (-2A+3Ax-3B+Bx=0) and -3A+Ax+2B-3Bx=2. Not too sure what to set x equal to in this case.

Answer (score 2):

the characteristic equation is
$$m^2+4m+5=0$$
$$m=-2\pm i$$
$$y_c=e^{-2x}[C_1\cos x+C_2\sin x]$$
now we should find the particular solution
let $$y_p=e^{-2x}[A\cos x+B\sin x]$$
because the similarity between the particular and complementry  soultions, so the particular solution should be multiplied by x
$$y_p=xe^{-2x}[A\cos x+B\sin x]$$
then you can find the $A$ and $B$

Comment: for the second one, how would i go about the change of variables, the website i was using to teach myself never covered change of variables.

Comment: @ForrestChanningHunter do do you mean about the particular solution

Comment: I can find A and B. I asked a second question starting with "the other one". not sure how to do change of variables here. The website I'm using never covered this.

Comment: There's no change of variables here